# Is there any reorder event that I can listen to?

Tags: octobercms

In the backend, I need to export data file whenever my model is modified, no matter it's saved, updated or reordered. The following function works just fine except the reorder (drag & drop feature, aka the Reorder behavior). Can anyone suggest a way to deal with the reorder?

```
// after the model is saved, either created or updated.   
public function afterSave()
{
  // export data here or fire the my export event
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm it seems there is trait which is doing soting work `sorting and saving`

and its located here `vendor\october\rain\src\Database\Traits\Sortable.php` its added to model to make it sort-able.

```
/**
 * Sets the sort order of records to the specified orders. If the orders is
 * undefined, the record identifier is used.
 * @param  mixed $itemIds
 * @param  array $itemOrders
 * @return void
 */
public function setSortableOrder($itemIds, $itemOrders = null)
{
    if (!is_array($itemIds)) {
        $itemIds = [$itemIds];
    }

    if ($itemOrders === null) {
        $itemOrders = $itemIds;
    }

    if (count($itemIds) != count($itemOrders)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid setSortableOrder call - count of itemIds do not match count of itemOrders');
    }

    foreach ($itemIds as $index => $id) {
        $order = $itemOrders[$index];
        $this->newQuery()->where($this->getKeyName(), $id)->update([$this->getSortOrderColumn() => $order]);
        // ======================================= 
        // YOUR EXPORT CODE CAN BE HERE
        // =======================================
    }
}
```

this method is called when `sorting happens` , so may be just `copy this method code in your model` and `override default behavior` write your `export logic` inside this method and it will be called every time `sorting happens`

> so far i guess this is the simplest logic i found.

if any doubt please comment.